# SQL Unique grouping scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is returning a pivot table from some time data:

```
SELECT *
FROM TIME
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,DATE,101) >= '2019-02-24' AND CONVERT(DATETIME,DATE,101) <= '2019-03-02'),
Pivoted AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM QueryTable
  PIVOT (max (DURATION) for DATE in ([02/24/2019],[02/25/2019],[02/26/2019],[02/27/2019],[02/28/2019],[03/01/2019],[03/02/2019])) as pvt
), ProcessTable As ( 
  SELECT 
    EmpID, JOB, ITEM, PITEM, PROJ, [02/24/2019],[02/25/2019],[02/26/2019],[02/27/2019],[02/28/2019],[03/01/2019],[03/02/2019], NOTE
  FROM Pivoted
  WHERE EmpID = '171'
  GROUP BY EmpID,  JOB, ITEM, PITEM, PROJ, [02/24/2019],[02/25/2019],[02/26/2019],[02/27/2019],[02/28/2019],[03/01/2019],[03/02/2019], NOTE
)
SELECT * FROM ProcessTable
```

The dates and the EmpID are dynamically filled in by a web app, these values are just placeholders. The current result from this query is this:

[image]

I would like to group the table once more to get a final result that looks like this:

[image]

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily express this as conditional aggregation:

```
select job, item, pitem,
       max(case when date = '2019-02-24' then duration end) as dur_20190224,
       max(case when date = '2019-02-25' then duration end) as dur_20190225,
       . . . 
from QueryTable
where . . .  -- your conditions here
group by job, item, pitem
```

I'm not sure how this fits into your web app, though.